# Delphi DBGrid Format Display Values

Tags: delphi, format, dbgrid

I need to format values in a `DBGrid` to display in a certain format ex `'#,##0.00'`. Any idea how to do that?

Regards, Pieter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each Field in your DataSet has two events: OnGetText and OnSetText. Use event OnGetText of desired fields and use Format function to format the value using a mask.

Answer (score 6):

you can use the [DisplayFormat](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TNumericField.DisplayFormat) property of the field to format.

check this sample

```
TFloatField(YourDataSet.FieldByName('field')).DisplayFormat := '#,##0.00';
```

Comment: Sure, but the event GetText gives more flexibility. For instance, you can use different masks is value is positive or negative.

Comment: If you need flexibility, but if not don't waste your time writing code for this.  For the positive/negative example, if you read the documentation you will notice DisplayFormat support "sections" separated by semicolons, for positive, negative and zeros.  So, you can use, for example:

    begin
      qOrdersTotal.DisplayFormat := ',0.00;(,0.00);Zero';
    end;

For more info  read http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TNumericField_DisplayFormat.html