# Delphi: how to find and format DBGrid field

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, dbgrid

I use DBGrid with Delphi XE2 to show some query results.
In the result some (integer) Fields represent a duration in seconds that I want to show in some format like "hh:mm:ss"
I don't know in advance the fields order since the queries may be different but I know the fields name that I want to format.
What is the most efficient way to do it ?

Comment: Try using the [`DisplayFormat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TNumericField.DisplayFormat) property check a sample here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619835/delphi-dbgrid-format-display-values

Comment: @RRUz - make an answer - this is the proper variant for the localized question like this

Comment: @RRUZ I yet use DisplayFormat for other purposes, but it seemed to me that there is not any Format string that can change seconds to 'hh:mm:ss'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While answer by @AndreaBoc is correct (but only answers one of your questions), it is somewhat repetitive: copy-pasting the same calculations looks an anti-pattern to me.

Repetitiveness may be removed by using http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Math.DivMod

```
procedure TForm1.PrettyPrintSeconds(Sender: TField;
  var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
var
  hh,mm,ss: Word;
begin
  DivMod( Sender.AsInteger, 3600, hh, mm );
  DivMod( mm, 60, mm, ss );
  Text := Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d',[hh,mm,ss]);
end;
```

*Additionally, if you **really** want be efficient ( but then why using `TDataset`? ) you may replace too flexible Format function with 3 temp string variables and old-style `Str` procedure like outlined at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.SysUtils.IntToStr :-)*

This should be set for http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TField.OnGetText

That is better than copy-pasting same operations twice and more, increasin both CPU time and chance to make silly typo.

Then there is the next part of question: *don't know the fields order... but I know the fields name that I want to format*. That means that you should tune this field after the query opened:

```
procedure TDataModule1.Query1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
var F: TField;
begin
    F := DataSet.FindField('MY-Name-For-Time');
    if F = nil 
       then (* .... no such field - do something about it .... *)
       else F.OnGetText := TForm1.PrettyPrintSeconds;
end;
```

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.AfterOpen
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.FindField
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.FieldByName

*From `BeforeClose` event you may remove (set to `nil`) this event handler similarly. Just for that rare check that the same TField object gets re-used for different purpose later. It should not happen except for some very exotic situations, but just to "clean after oneself".*

---

There is less effective (from CPU point of view) but more VCL in spirit approach as well.

For the query in its `AfterOpen` event: look for the given field name like above, and if found then:

1. save the result for the later use (as linear string search inside `FieldByName` is not the most effecient operation per se, so should not repeat it for every value displaying)

   - Proper but somewhat tedious way would be to make new `TTimeField` property for the query owner.
   - under Win32 you may (ab)use `Int32` property `TDataSet.Tag`, storing there the pointer via type-cast. That is fragile, unsafe and unportable code, but storing `Integer`, `pointer` and `TObject` values in any of those variables is somewhat "old Delphi style" *( like in TStringList.Objects )* and it works, if you're careful and only interested in Win32.
2. add a calculated field of datetime type

   - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TTimeField
   - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TField.FieldKind
   - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Calculating_Fields
3. set `'hh:nn:ss'` as format for that new field: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDateTimeField.DisplayFormat
4. Make the new field friendly to DBGrid and other db-aware controls

   - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TField.DisplayLabel
   - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TField.DisplayWidth
5. Make the original field invisible or remove its column from the grid - you have the new field instead.

Then set `OnCalcFields` on the query like:

```
// 1. Delphi TDateTime is double and 1 day equals to 1.0
// 2. Multiplication is more efficient than division - do it by pen and paper and see
procedure TDataModule1.Query1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
const coeff = 1.0 / ( 24 * 60 * 60 );
begin
  MyCalcField.AsTime := MySourceField.AsInteger * coeff;
end;
```

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnCalcFields

Then you would be able to use the new virtual field in every place where Delphi routines would expect `TDateTime` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OnGetText event of the field for you request:

```
procedure TForm1.Table1secondsGetText(Sender: TField;
  var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
var
  seconds,hh,mm,ss:Integer;
begin
  seconds := Sender.AsInteger;
  hh := seconds div 3600;
  mm := (seconds - (hh * 3600)) div 60;
  ss := (seconds - (hh * 3600) - (mm * 60));
  Text := Format('%.2d:%.2d:%.2d',[hh,mm,ss]);
end;
```

for example 185 seconds will be displayed in this way: 00:03:05

Comment: If you want to use this in more than one place, create a library function SecsToTime(Sec: Integer): string;